# Xamarin forms android json - Async call hangs/never returns

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hello I'm working on a android app in Xamarin forms thats getting json data from a service and its supposed to display that data in The ContactInfo class however when you click on the button that's supposed to get that data and then display it and then take you to the ContactInfo class it hangs and after a minute my galaxy s7 tells me that app isn't responding would you like to close it?
I have no idea what i'm doing wrong

here's my Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ReadyMo.ContactInfo">
              <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContactInfoList}" HasUnevenRows="true">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Frame Padding="0,0,0,8" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
            <Frame.Content>
              <Frame Padding="15,15,15,15"   OutlineColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Frame.Content>
                  <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label x:Name="FirstName" Text="{Binding First_Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>
                        <Label x:Name ="LastName" Text="{Binding Last_Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>
                        <Label x:Name="County" Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>
                        <Label x:Name ="Adress" Text="{Binding Address1}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>
                          <Label x:Name ="City" Text="{Binding Address2}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>
                        <Label x:Name="Number"  Text="{Binding BusinessPhone}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>   
                  </StackLayout>
                </Frame.Content>
              </Frame>
            </Frame.Content>
          </Frame>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's my codebehind:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ReadyMo.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ReadyMo
{
    public partial class ContactInfo : ContentPage
    {
        private County item;


        public static async Task<string> GetContactString(string contactid)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var url = $"http://sema.dps.mo.gov/county/service.php?id={contactid}";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responsetext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responsetext;
            }
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);


        }

        public ContactInfo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        List <ContactInfoModel> ContactInfoList;
        public ContactInfo(County item)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.item = item;

            var contactpagetext = ContactManager.GetContactString(item.id);
            var contact = GetContactString("001").Result;
            //need to add update database code 

            //Convert Jason string to object

             ContactInfoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactInfoModel>>(contact);
             this.BindingContext = ContactInfoList;





            //Floodplain Administrators



        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the async code out of the constructor. A common approach to this is to override `OnAppearing()` to perform the work. You would also probably want to display an `ActivityIndicator` in your UI until the data has been loaded:

```
public partial class ContactInfo : ContentPage
{
    private County item;

    public static async Task<string> GetContactString(string contactid)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var url = $"http://sema.dps.mo.gov/county/service.php?id={contactid}";
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responsetext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responsetext;
        }
        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }

    public ContactInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContactInfoList = new ObservableCollection<ContactInfoModel>();
    }

    ObservableCollection<ContactInfoModel> ContactInfoList;

    public ContactInfo(County item) : this()
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.BindingContext = ContactInfoList;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing ()
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;
        var contact = await GetContactString(item.id);
        var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactInfoModel>>(contact);
        foreach (var model in models)
            ContactInfoList.Add(model);
    }
}
```

To fix the binding problem, recognize that you are assigning the list itself to your page's BindingContext. You can do one of two things:

1. Change `ItemsSource="{Binding ContactInfoList}"` in your ListView XAML to `ItemsSource="{Binding .}"`.
2. Change `this.BindingContext = ContactInfoList;` in your constructor to `this.BindingContext = this;`.

Option #1 is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the reply that took care of the hanging issue but it's not displaying any content in the listview? its just showing a white page any thoughts on why its doing this? thanks for all the help so far! :)

Comment: Sure, I added some more to the answer to handle that part.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var contact = GetContactString("001").Result;
```

It's [causing a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain in full on my blog.

To fix this, you have to first realize that the UI must display *immediately*. When the OS calls your code, you can't wait for an HTTP request to complete before responding; that's simply not allowed.

What you *can* do is *start* the HTTP request and display something else (like a spinner or "loading..." message) immediately. Then, when the HTTP request completes, *update* your display with the new information.

I have more details and sample code in my [MSDN article on async MVVM data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Comment: thank you for the response so how would you suggest I fix this issue based on my code? I read your blog post and its for a windows app this is a xamrain froms android app  so how would I go about implementing a loading screen while the data is being pulled from the service? Thanks once again for all your help! :)

Comment: @Phoneswapshop: Did you read the MSDN article? It applies to all XAML stacks. You should be able to use the ideas in the article along with something like [NotifyTask](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs) to data-bind asynchronous operations.

Comment: i did but i'm having issues incorporating your examples into my project can you please suggest what to to based on my project thanks for all the help so far :)